# SPARC and Assembly

Tags: programming-languages, assembly

I'm currently self teaching myself programming and became familiar with Python, Java and C and I'm confused as to what are the differences between Assembly and SPARC Assembly and whether or not I should learning Assembly first then SPARC.

Answer (score 3):

[Assembler languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) are processor (or [CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit)) specific. Each processor has its own assembler language (which maps to a different [machine language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code)). So [SPARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC) processors use SPARC assembler, [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) processors use x86-64 assembler, etc.

For a few processors, including x86-64 used in most laptops & desktops in 2015, you might have two different syntaxes so two flavors of assembly language (so called Intel vs ATT) which are translated to the *same* machine code.

(BTW, x86-64 understands both 32 bits [ia32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32) and 64 bits amd64 machine code and assembler, as if the chip had a mixture of two processors; it actually has several modes: the old 16 bit one -from 8086-, the 32 bit one -from i386-, the amd64 one, etc...).

Read wikipage about [instruction sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) (which is what your processor understands, and what its assembler is emitting in [object files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) with [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29) information, e.g. for the [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29)) Notice that [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) means a family of instruction sets (with a common base), because of extensions like [SSE3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE3), [AVX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions), etc.

The SPARC and [MIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set) instruction sets are probably easier to understand than x86. You might even look into [MMIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX) (an hypothetical instruction set for teaching purposes) or [Open RISC V](http://riscv.org/) (a free specification instruction set).

<sup>It is a bit more complex, since many instructions sets have both 32 bits and 64 bits variants.</sup>